# how can let the smart contract send a transaction to a node

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am writing a smart contract which create a document signed by two parties and then let the smart contract send the signed document to someone to save it and do some analysis.

Now I have the signed document by party A and B, how I can let the smart contract invoke a function to send this document to the third part who will do the analysis??? how should I write the function???

How I can translate this action into solidity "Once the document has been signed by both A and B, the smart contract will send it the analysis unit to start the analysis process".

Thank you

Comment: Think this could be done by using ethereum alarm clock ?? I a thinking if can set a transaction to be executed if a new document has been added to the list. I can send it immediately after signing the doc by the second party but do you think the cost of this call should be paid by the last one who sign the doc ???

Comment: I would just have an event thrown when the 2nd party signs the document. The event would then be the trigger for the 3rd party to retrieve the document for analysis. This way the 2 signees pay for their transaction fee (roughly the same amount) and the 3rd party pays for finalizing the activity with the smart contract.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your comment. But what I don't understand, how I can let the 3rd party knows that he should trigger or invoke the method of retrieving the document, should he check the event state every period of time? I have confused what the function body will be? What If sending the document to the 3rd part is time sensitive, I mean the doc should be sent to the 3rd party immediately after signed by 2nd party and should not wait to check the event state and retrieve the doc ?!! -Thanks

Comment: The contract throws an event when the 2nd party signs. You have a client that listens for the event and then triggers the document retrieval. It's as "immediate" as it can be in the Ethereum world. Read more about events here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode (you, of course need program according to solidity specification, if we are talking about ethereum):

```
    address thirdParty;
    bool signedByA;
    bool signedByB;
    byte[] docData;

  function signDoc() public {
    if(sender == "Aaddress") {
       signedByA = true;
    }
    if(sender == "Baddress") {
       signedByB = true;
    }

    if(signedByA && signedByB) {
      thirdParty.sendTransaction(docData);
    }       
}
```

Details depends on your needs. Who and how sign, do A and B predefined or can be defined dynamically etc.